# Transfer custom type to String

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I've custom type:

```
open class HashTag: Equatable {

    open var text: String
    open var isRemovable: Bool
    open var hasHashSymbol: Bool
    open var configuration: HashtagConfiguration?

    public init(word: String, withHashSymbol: Bool = true, isRemovable: Bool = true) {
        self.text = word
        self.isRemovable = isRemovable
        self.hasHashSymbol = withHashSymbol

        if hasHashSymbol {
            self.text = "#" + text
        }
    }

    public static func == (lhs: HashTag, rhs: HashTag) -> Bool {
        return lhs.text == rhs.text
    }
}
```

I want to transfer it to ordinary String array and then transfer back. For example, for:

```
   var tags = [
                HashTag(word: "this"),
                HashTag(word: "is"),
                HashTag(word: "an"),
                HashTag(word: "example")
    ]
```

I want to transfer to

```
var tagsTransferred = ["this","is","an","example"]
```

And back transfer:

```
var tagsTransferred = ["this","is","an","example"]
```

to:

```
   var tags = [
                HashTag(word: "this"),
                HashTag(word: "is"),
                HashTag(word: "an"),
                HashTag(word: "example")
    ]
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `Array.map(_:)`.

Comment: Are you asking how to turn a `[String]` into a `[HashTag]`? Or are you asking how to let the compiler automatically turn the literal `["this","is","an","example"]` to a `[HashTag]`?

Comment: Any of this variants will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` method in `Array` is made for transforming each element of the array, i.e. exactly what you are doing.

To convert a `[String]` to a `[HashTag]`:

```
let hashTagArray = stringArray.map { HashTag(word: $0) }
```

To convert a `[HashTag]` to `[String]`:

```
let stringArray = hashTagArray.map { $0.text }
```

---

Additionally, if you would like something like this to be possible:

```
// the string array literal is automatically converted to [HashTag]
let hashTagArray: [HashTag] = ["this", "is", "an", "example"]
```

You can do:

```
open class HashTag : Equatable, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {

    ...

    public typealias StringLiteralType = String
    public required convenience init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(word: value)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also do `stringArray.map(HashTag.init)`, and starting in Swift 5.1, you can use `hashTagArray.map(\.text)` :)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica No `stringArray.map(HashTag.init)` would not work with default values

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I thought `.map(HashTag.init)` wouldn't work because the other parameters are "only" optional parameters, and that the compiler won't be smart enough to figure out, but apparently it is... Was this always a thing? I remember optional parameters not working well with directly referring to the method...

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried it on a playground and it does work though... Oh wait... it's the string literal init...

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh I didn't notice those. But apparently now that's possible. That's a surprise to me, too.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica No it doesn't actually. I _thought_ it's working, but it's actually just resolving to the `init(stringLiteral:)` that I added...

Comment: @Sweeper yes you need to provide an initializer with only one parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compactMap` function for both case.

1. From [HashTag] to [String]

   ```
   var tags = [
       HashTag(word: "this"), 
       HashTag(word: "is"), 
       HashTag(word: "an"), 
       HashTag(word: "example")
   ]

   let arrString = tags.compactMap { (tag) -> String in
       tag.text.removeFirst() // This line just to remove "#"
       return tag.text
   }
   ```
2. From [String] to [HashTag]

   ```
   var strings = ["this", "is", "an", "example"]

   let arrHashtag = strings.compactMap {
       return HashTag(word: $0)
   }
   ```

Comment: Using compactMap on an array of non optional elements is pointless as well as using it with a non fallible initializer.